# VS Studio copy LocalDB database

Tags: .net, localdb

When you create a blank ASP.net web form project you get this nice folder called Account with all the useful login stuff. It also gives you a database to play with.

I would like to copy that database to my web server and use it for logins myself.

Where is the file located?

I have found that when I connect to .\SQLEXPRESS using SQL Server Management Studio there are System Databases; master, model, msdb, tempdb. But I am not sure which one to use.

Is it even a good idea to use this database? If not, then how should I structure my logins database so that it works with the forms in the Account folder?

Answer (score 0):

Check you web.config file. There should be a path specified to the localdb file.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it will be in the User profile folder Something like

```
C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```

[Check this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It got generated in the App_Data folder of the project as soon as I entered the first data. Thanks guys